# as2 FileReference() issue

Tags: actionscript-2, filereference

I have a simple swf file upload script that uploads a file as soon as user selects it. It works fine however I'm trying to pass the saved filename from the php script (simple echo "file_name.txt";) back to the swf so it can pass it back to the form via javascript.

Here's  a simple snippet of the AS2 code, can someone who has some experience with the FileReference component help me out with a solution to get the output from the php script?

```
var file_fr:FileReference = new FileReference();
var list_obj:Object = new Object();
list_obj.onComplete = function() {
    // need to get response text from script.php
}
file_fr.addListener(list_obj);

if (!file_fr.upload("/path/to/script.php")) {
    feedback.text = "error";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe FileReference.upload isn't going to be made smart enough to return anything other than success fail codes. So what you need to do is pass a UID on the end of your URL and then use that to query php on what it did on its end in another call.

Rereading your post, do you want the local file or the remote file name? Local should be available in the FileReference.

Here is old code I dug up -

Note: This is AS3. And it deals with 3 images, so...

[AS3 FileReference Example](http://pastebin.com/2JDnxpTB)

And then the PHP

[PHP AS3 FileReference Example](http://pastebin.com/r5j366L0)

Comment: I was stuck using AS2 as it's a component I found under GPL, however I am going to do a custom AS3 version so you're links are helpful. If anyone else runs into a similar issue with AS2, the solution is list_obj.onUploadCompleteData = function(fileRef:FileReference, src:String){}, the src string contains the output from the php script (took an hour of googling to find a useable example).